# Groupby-Transform over an empty data frame raises exception

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Why does the following code raise an exception:

```
# creates empty data frame with two columns
my_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["a", "b"])
# groups by the values in column "a" and transforms the values in "b" to be the sum
my_df.groupby("a")["b"].transform(lambda x: x.sum())
```

However this results in this error:

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

It works if `my_df` is not empty:

```
list_of_numbers = [[0, 1],
                   [0, 2],
                   [1, 10]]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_numbers, columns=["a", "b"])
my_df.groupby("a")["b"].transform(lambda x: x.sum())
```

```
0     3
1     3
2    10
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

but `my_df` is coming from some other parts of the application so it can be empty. I'm using Pandas 0.20.3.

Comment: `if not my_df.empty:` ?

Comment: @RafaelC Yes, but why would `.transform` fail to take that into account?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L8929-L8936, check the

Comment: Transform calls core\reshape\concat.py and there they made the decision that `Any None objects will be dropped silently unless they are all None in which case a ValueError will be raised`. So you get your error, since everything is None.

Comment: @ALollz so what would be a solution to this other than doing an explicit empty check every time I need to do a groupby-transform?

Comment: I'd go with RafaelC's suggestion

Comment: @ALollz I was hoping there's a cleaner solution but I will go with that if there's absolutely no other way around it.

Comment: Well you can get around it if you instead `.apply` and map the result, instead of transforming. That will not cause an error for the empty `DataFrame`

Comment: @ALollz Can you expand more on that?

Comment: Use: `my_df.a.map(my_df.groupby("a")["b"].sum())`. Apply gives you the sum per `a`, and then you use map to bring that to all columns in the original `DataFrame`. The only difference is that the result has `Name: a` instead of `Name: b`

Comment: @ALollz That's a good enough solution. If you want to put that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.groupby.transform](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.3/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L3636-L3665) calls [core/reshape/concat.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.3/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py#L32-L38) The documentation explains what happens in the case where concat receives only None objects.

> Any None objects will be dropped silently unless
>           they are all None in which case a ValueError will be raised

However, a normal `groupby` with apply, or built in functions doesn't seem to have this issue. If you don't want to check for this empty condition every time you can instead map the grouping column with the result of `.groupby().sum()` to accomplish the same thing as transform in this case.

#### First Case:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["a", "b"])
my_df.a.map(my_df.groupby("a")["b"].sum())
#Series([], Name: a, dtype: float64)
```

#### Second Case:

```
list_of_numbers = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 10]]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_numbers, columns=["a", "b"])
my_df.a.map(my_df.groupby("a")["b"].sum())
#0     3
#1     3
#2    10
#Name: a, dtype: int64
```

The only thing that changes is the `Name` of the resulting series.

Comment: This approach works for single columns, but what if there are multiple group by columns and multiple sum columns?